# OnType Javascript but want the type to match a word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, input

I am working on an input box for a promo code. We have several promo codes. However, on one promo code, if the user types in "springchicken", then I need it to open, or toggle an additional radio input for a selection. Is that possible? I am thinking I could use onType, but I don't really know how to write that. See example below. I need it to so something like that but the words that are typed must match "SpringChicken". How can I write that?

```
 <input type="text" name="promo" id="promo" value="" size="22" placeholder="Enter Promo Code"  ontype="document.getElementsByClassName('promoradio')[0].style.display='block';" />

 <!--Need the following DIV to appear once "SpringChicken" is entered on the fly-->
 <div class="promoradio">
   <input type="radio" name="promopkg" value="1" /><label>Promo Package #1</label>
   <input type="radio" name="promopkg" value="2" /><label>Promo Package #2</label>
 </div>
```

Comment: `ontype` is not a javascript event. Try `onkeypress` or `onkeyup`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this jquery solution: (Edited so it won't be case sensitive)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

       $("#promo").keyup(function() {
           var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
           if (value == "springchicken") {
              $(".promoradio").show();
           } else {
              $(".promoradio").hide();
           }
       });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: No explanation of solution, -1. -1 again because jQuery is so overkill for something this simple in normal javascript.

Comment: @RUJordan You're downvoting something that works when he tagged jquery? Plus I think "keyup", "show" and "hide" are pretty self explanatory...

Comment: If they were self explanatory, the OP wouldn't have asked this question. IMO, you don't need a 90kb library to show/hide a div when an input matches a certain word.

Comment: This looks like something I will try. Is there a way to make it not case sensitive?

Comment: @RUJordan Of course you don't ever "need" jquery, but it often makes it a lot easier!

Comment: I wouldn't call this one of those cases, but yes, it is much nicer when worrying about things like cross browser compatibility.

Comment: @RUJordan The question is tagged jQuery implying that they are already using jQuery, it's absolutely reasonable to use it in the answer. Adding a bunch of ugly native DOM code when it is not needed would be silly.

Comment: It worked the first time without the Case Sensitive, but this code won't work either way. Is there a solution? typo?

Comment: It works, I had an error on my end! THANK YOU!!! !!!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things wrong here.

First, there is no `ontype` event for javascript. You'll want `onkeypress` (for when they key goes down) or `onkeyup` for when the key goes up.

Second, inline javascript is ugly and bad practice. Use something like this:

```
var x = document.getElementById("input element");
x.onkeyup = function() {
    var word = x.innerHTML;
    if (word.toUpperCase() === "SPRINGCHICKEN") { //if you're not worried about case sensitivity or unicode
        document.getElementsByClassName('promoradio')[0].style.display='block';
    }
}
```

Assuming the `class` `promoradio` has `display:hidden` here initially.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<input type="text" name="promo" id="promo" value="" size="22" placeholder="Enter Promo Code"   />

 <!--Need the following DIV to appear once "SpringChicken" is entered on the fly-->
 <div class="promoradio">
   <input type="radio" name="promopkg" value="1" /><label>Promo Package #1</label>
   <input type="radio" name="promopkg" value="2" /><label>Promo Package #2</label>
 </div>



 <script>
    var textToMatch = "springchicken";
function matchWord(e){
    if(document.getElementById('promo').value.trim().toLowerCase() == textToMatch){
        document.getElementsByClassName('promoradio')[0].style.display='block';
    }else{
        document.getElementsByClassName('promoradio')[0].style.display='none';
    }
}

document.getElementById('promo').onkeyup = matchWord;
    </script>

css:

.promoradio{
 display:none;   
}
```

Check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sesubash/rVx8A/1/)

Hope it helps.